# React append 5 items in each div using for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this prop loop that pushes and shows 30 items

```
var newArr = [];
for (var key in this.props.data) {

     // for (var i = start; i < start + 5; i++) {
     //     if (i > array.length) return;

     //     $("#output").append(array[k]);
     // }

     newArr.push(<div><Dates key={key} /></div>);
}
```

I need to show this 5 items in a row so wrap it 5 items in each div like jQuery code that commented out possible ?

Comment: You need to show all the divs in a group of fives wrapped in parent div?

Comment: what is the structure of `this.props.data`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not best algorithm out there but I think you want to do something like this:

```
var dates = [];
var rows = [];
for (var key in this.props.data) { 
  if (this.props.data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    dates.push(<Dates key={key} />);

    if(dates.length === 5) {
      rows.push(
        <div>
          {dates}
        </div>
      );

      dates = [];
    }
  }
}

// final step
rows.push(
  <div>
    {dates}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work, so this is really just code golf, but here's my crack at it.  Using forEach lets you not worry about miscalculation with an index, code accounts for having a non-full final row.

```
var newArr = [], row=[], rowLength=5;
this.props.data.forEach((item, index) => {
  row.push(item);
  if ((row.length === rowLength) || index === this.props.data.length - 1) {
    newArr.push(<div>{row}</div>);
    row = [];
  }
})
```